# Lists.ForEach select with criteria by using LINQ/LAMBDA

Tags: c#, linq

I have List , I; only want to select base on certain criteria with LinQ/LAMBDA

My Code is

```
Lists.ForEach(x => x.IsAnimal == false { /* Do Something */ } );
```

I am getting error "only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement" in this part  `x.IsAnimal == false`

i know we can achieve this easily with a for loop but I want to learn more by using LinQ/LAMBDA

Answer (score 23):

Just use *Where* and *ToList* before using ForEach

```
Lists.Where(x => !x.IsAnimal).ToList().ForEach(...)
```

Comment: The result of [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) is an `IEnumerable<T>`. At least in the BCL, there is no `ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`, so your code will not compile.

Comment: Where won't return a `List<T>`. A `ToList()` is missing: `Lists.Where(x => !x.IsAnimal).ToList().ForEach(`

Answer (score 19):

That's not working because you can't have `false{}` construct.

```
Lists.ForEach(x => { 
                  if(x.IsAnimal){
                       //Do Something
                  }
             } );
```

Answer (score 6):

Please read up on the [syntax of lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx): A lambda expression represents a method; the part before the `=>` is the list of parameters, and the part afterwards is either a single expression whose result will be returned, or a method body.

You can add your restriction within that method body:

```
Lists.ForEach(x => {
                  if (!x.IsAnimal) {
                      // do something
                  }
              });
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be something like this:

```
things.Where(x => !x.IsAnimal).ToList().ForEach(x => { // do something });
```

I can see people are complaining about having to build new list to use ForEach. You could do the same thing with Select and stick to IEnumerable:

```
things.Where(x => !x.IsAnimal).Select(x => 
{
    // do something with it
    return x; // or transform into something else.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that there *is* a difference between lists.foreach and a normal foreach. A 'normal' for each uses an enumerator, making it illegal to change the list that is iterated. the lists.foreach() does not use an enumerator (if I'm not mistaking it uses an indexer on the background) making it possible to change items in the array as you go.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes! And in most cases it's much easier and clearer to just use `foreach`. It almost feels like a mistake that the authors of .NET 2.0 decided to include `List<>.ForEach(Action<>)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "ForEach" on different types of collections you should write an extension for IEnumerable:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtension
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T d in data)
        {
            action(d);
        }
    }
}
```

With this extension you can filter before using ForEach and you don't have to form a new list with the filtered items:

```
lists.Where(x => !x.IsAnimal).ForEach( /* Do Something */  );
```

I prefere the standard version:

```
foreach (var x in lists.Where(x => !x.IsAnimal)) { /* Do Something */ }
```

Not very long and clearly a loop with sideeffects.

Answer (score -2):

Try such code:

```
 class A {
    public bool IsAnimal { get; set; }
    public bool Found { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<A> lst = new List<A>();

        lst.Add(new A() { IsAnimal = false, Found = false });
        lst.Add(new A() { IsAnimal = true, Found = false  });
        lst.Add(new A() { IsAnimal = true, Found = false  });
        lst.Add(new A() { IsAnimal = false, Found = false  });

        // Here you first iterate to find only items with (IsAnimal == false)
        // then from IEnumerable we need to get a List of items subset
        // Last action is to execute ForEach on the subset where you can put your actions...
        lst.Where(x => x.IsAnimal == false).ToList().ForEach(y => y.Found = true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brotip, the `== false` and `== true` are not needed. Can be `!x.IsAnimal` and `y.Found` respectively.

Comment: @Arran thank for your remark, it is only for clarity of code.